# Git merging issue

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

Following is the git flow that we are about to follow. But the problem is we have to restrict people from re basing the feature branch from the developer branch. We should only let people rebase their feature branch from the release branch. 
Restriction should be that when a user trying to merge a feature branch which is created from the developer branch or re based from the developer branch that merge should be rejected. Is that can be done?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood your question. You are looking for a way to restrict developers from creating feature branches from develop.

Below code snippet will help you to identify parent branch of a feature branch. You may have to add this to server side git pre-receive hook script.

```
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` 
parent_branch=`git show-branch -a 2>/dev/null | grep '\*' | grep -v "$branch" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'`
if $parent_branch="develop"; then
    echo "please use release as base branch"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Authorization for Merge requests](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/authorization_for_merge_requests.html)", you have two ways to enforce authorization.

Since in your case you don't want rebase on top of master, I would consider the **forking workflow**, where `master`/`hotfix` branches are in one repo, `feature`/`dev` branches in another repo, where developers are registered.

That way, developers can only make merge request to `master`, with a possibility for the integrator to accept/reject a merge request based on its provenance.